# Sugarcrm task email template

Tags: email, templates, task, sugarcrm

When a task is created from case page (activities subpanel) an email is sent to the assignee. My requirement is to add custom fields to this email template in upgrade-safe manner.

I have copied the *en_us.notify_template.php* to *custom/include/language* folder, but how to assign/add variables to this template. I can assign it in */modules/Tasks/Task.php* but this is not upgrade-safe.

How can i do it in upgrade safe manner?

Answer (score 3):

See this developer blog post...

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/05/10/howto-customize-the-assignment-notifications-for-a-custom-module/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have already gone through the link you have shared but unfortunately that did not solve my problem.
Let me re-phrase my query: As per my understanding, in the post you have shared the custom module is built within root/modules folder and  set_notification_body function is defined in the bean class of that module. I want to override that function within custom/modules/Tasks folder, how do I do that? 
Thanks

Comment: You can't in the custom folder, only in the actual bean itself. And yes, it's not upgrade safe.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.